# Type error when trying to use mapped projection with Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to use Slick's mapped projections (Version 1.0.0-RC1). But the following code, which follows the examples on the website (as there doesn't seem to be any proper documentation nor usable scaladocs) yields a type error:

```
object PDFDocs extends Table[(String,Option[String],String)]("DOCUMENTS"){
  def id = column[String]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def title = column[Option[String]]("TITLE")
  def tags = column[String]("TAGS")
  def * = (id ~ title ~ tags).<>[PDFDocument](PDFDocument,PDFDocument unapply _)
}

case class PDFDocument(name: String,
                       title: Option[String],
                       tags: String)
```

Here is the produced error:

```
error: type mismatch; 
found: scala.slick.lifted.MappedProjection[docman.rdb.PDFDocument,(String,Option[String], String)] 
required: scala.slick.lifted.ColumnBase[(String, Option[String], String)] 
def * = (id ~ title ~ tags).<>[PDFDocument](PDFDocument,PDFDocument unapply _)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Off the top of my head, shouldn't the first line be:

```
object PDFDocs extends Table[PDFDocument]("DOCUMENTS") {
```

Comment: That's "even" nicer and works. Thank you, I've overlooked this in the examples.

Comment: +100. i've been looking for an answer forever, and all the samples i looked at had the table class parametrized based on the members, not as a whole model case class. i've been banging my head against the wall all day long. thank you.